# Correlation between $x$ and $x^{2}$

Tags: correlation

Parts of my question have been answered on the website separately. I was trying to find a way to reconcile between the two. The two parts are:

1. The correlation between $x$ and $x^{2}$ is **not zero** if, let's say, $x$ is distributed uniformly between $0$ and $1$. However, if we shift the $x$ values by $-0.5$, so that $x$ is distributed symmetrically around the y-axis, the correlation becomes close to $0$. This is covered in the answers here: [Why are $x$ and $x^2$ correlated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58309/why-are-x-and-x2-correlated)
2. Correlation is translation invariant. This is covered here: [Pearson correlation - can negative values in your data artificially increase the size of the correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422411/pearson-correlation-can-negative-values-in-your-data-artificially-increase-the)

My question is, if correlation is indeed translation invariant, why does it change from non-zero to close to $0$ in the $x$ and $x^{2}$ case after the shift by $-0.5$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correlation between $x$ and $y$ is translation invariant:

$$ \text{cor}(x,y) = \text{cor}(x+a,y+b). $$

Thus,

$$ \text{cor}(x,x^2) = \text{cor}(x+a,x^2+b). $$

However, you are not comparing these two quantities. You are comparing $\text{cor}(x,x^2)$ and

$$ \text{cor}(x+a,(x+a)^2)=\text{cor}(x+a,x^2+2ax+a^2) \neq \text{cor}(x+a,x^2+b). $$

The important difference is in the $2ax$ term in the middle expression, which is not a constant $b$ but varies with $x$.

Comment: $\text{cor}\left(x+a,(x+a)^2\right)=\text{cor}\left(x,x^2\right) +2a\, \text{var}(x)$